# Thread What is the difference between

Tags: c#, multithreading

What is the difference between

```
Thread t = new Thread (new ThreadStart (Go));
```

and

```
Thread t = new Thread (Go);
```

where Go is a method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None, I gess. The constructor of `Thread` takes a `ThreadStart` "construct" which is of type `delegate`.

```
// constructor of Thread
public Thread(ThreadStart start);
```

`ThreadStart` is defined as:

```
namespace System.Threading
{
    // Summary:
    //     Represents the method that executes on a System.Threading.Thread.
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public delegate void ThreadStart();
}
```

Since every method can be used as a delegate you can directly pass yours into the constructor. By explicitly writing..

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(Go))
```

..you simply wrap it again.

Answer (score 7):

The only time there is a difference is if `Go` is a method-group that could match multiple `Thread` constructor overloads - for example, because there is a constructor for both `ThreadStart` and `ParameterizedThreadStart`, the following methods would make the `new Thread(Go)` version ambiguous:

```
static void Go() { }
static void Go(object val) { }
```

The `new Thread (new ThreadStart (Go))` disambiguates that by explicitly declaring the delegate type, but: other than that they are identical, on C# 2 or above. Note: prior to C# 2, the shorter version was not legal syntax.

Answer (score 4):

None. They are the same thing.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart(v=vs.110).aspx) states this:

> Visual Basic and C# users can omit the `ThreadStart` or `ParameterizedThreadStart` delegate constructor when creating a thread. [...] In C#, simply specify the name of the thread procedure. The compiler selects the correct delegate constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The second is one is a shortcut! Basically, does the same thing. But, inside of the object threadstart there are a set of parameters that you can inform.